# Where is System.Json in MonoDevelop on OSX?

Tags: json, macos, mono

I've got MonoDevelop 3.1.1 running on OSX.  I want to use System.Json but I can't find it anywhere.  When Editing References I can't see anything that looks like System.Json.  How do I make it available in my project?

Answer (score 1):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.json.jsonobject.aspx), it should be in System.Runtime.Serialization assembly. And you should be targetting the 4.5 profile.

BTW upgrading to Xamarin Studio (MonoDevelop 4.0) is highly recommended.